# SimpleDateFormat with pattern yyyyMMddhhmmss unable to parse date "20160327020727"

Tags: java, date, java-8, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I am getting an exception when parsing date `20160327020727` with format `yyyyMMddhhmmss`. Note that the lenient is set to false.

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
    df.setLenient(false);
    try {
        Date dt = df.parse("20160327020727");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is parsing other dates with the same format and it is working as expected. Why is this happening?

Comment: This works fine for me, what exception are you getting?

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20160327020727"

Comment: would this have to do something with your local time?

Comment: Possibly something to do with you using `hh` which is the 12 hour format. Do you want `HH` for the 24 hour format.

Comment: One error is that it probably should not be `hh` (**12** hour format) but `HH` (**24** hour format).

Comment: Wouldn't setLenient(false) make this a strict parser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time) changes to summer time the last Sunday of march, so there is no 2AM this day.

You go from 1:59 to 3:00

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because that time does not exist in your default time zone.

Try setting the timezone to `UTC` by doing `df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

In `CET` on the last Sunday of march it changes to summertime -> No 2AM on that day.

Answer (score -1):

Change it to `"yyyyMMdd HHmmss"`, so you can parse it easily.